# Make image maximum available width / height but without losing aspect ratio?

Tags: css

How can I resize an image so that it is as large as possible within its container without losing its aspect ratio?

This could be achieved with the picture element but I need to support IE9.

Note that in my example both the images are smaller than the container, but in reality some will be larger and have to be scaled down.

I cannot use background images and I would prefere not to use javascript if possible.

Images that are larger than there container can easily be scaled down with this:

```
img {
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 max-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

Therefore is there a way to trick the browser into thinking the image is larger than it is? This is similar to what you can do with the picture element where with the sizes attribute you can set the intended size of the image.

[image]

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdaboK

```
<div class="one">
<img src="http://www.nwhgeopark.com/wp-content/uploads/landscape.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="one">
<img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/519fW0fHKbL._SY300_.jpg" />
</div>

.one {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;

}

img {

}
```

Comment: Can't you use `background-image` insteed of html `<img>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgs = $('img');
  imgs.each(function(){
    var img = $(this);
    var width = img.width(); 
    var height = img.height();
    if(width < height){
       img.addClass('portrait');
    }else{
       img.addClass('landscape');
    }
  })
});
```

Which will add a class to images based on orientation. then add this css:

```
.landscape {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;  
}

.portrait {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

And it could behave as you are looking for:

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/8ug8wzfk/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest would be to separate portrait format pictures from landscape format ones and apply a responsive rule, try this, it should work

```
<div class="one">
<img class="landscape" src="http://www.nwhgeopark.com/wp-content/uploads/landscape.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="one">
<img class="portrait" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/519fW0fHKbL._SY300_.jpg" />
</div>
```

---

```
.one {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;

}

img.landscape {
  width: 100% !important;
  heigth: auto !important;
}

img.portrait {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Get the image width and height on the fly using jQuery and then set it by finding the multiplication factor according to the container width .....

```
<script>
getImageSize($('#image'), function(width, height) {
$('#info').text(width + ',' + height);
var multiplyFactor = ContainerWidth / width;
//Now set the image width and height
$(img).css({'width': width*multiplyFactor +'px', 
'height':height *    multiplyFactor+'px'});
});

 function getImageSize(img, callback) {
var $img = $(img);

var wait = setInterval(function() {
    var w = $img[0].naturalWidth,
        h = $img[0].naturalHeight;
    if (w && h) {
        clearInterval(wait);
        callback.apply(this, [w, h]);
    }
 }, 30);
 }
 </script>
```